# How to create an array with multiple fields in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a PHP array that outputs vehicle information relavent to one of three status of "status1","status2","status3" like so:

```
[Status1] => Array
(
   [$reg] => Array
      (
         [Make] => $data1
         [Color] => $data2
         [Engine] => $data3
      )
)
```

The data and reg variables are being pulled from a SQL database but I can't seem to work out how to push this data into an array that will output the in the example above?

Comment: want to show us how you are fetching the data from the DB?

Comment: `The data and reg variables are being pulled from a SQL database`-> please show us data sample and reg variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the rows from a table using the SQL query and loop through to build an array

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[$row['status']][$row['reg']] = array(
                                $row['Make'],
                                $row['Color'],
                                $row['Engine']
                            );
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, only thing missing is the reg. How can I put this in a third break down before the make, color, and engine. This will be the `$row['reg']`?